# SUM with group & condition

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT SUM(invoice_total) AS invoicetotal FROM `p_orders` WHERE `plain_date`='2020-12-23' AND `o_status`='Delivered' GROUP BY `order_no`
```

What I'm trying to do-
Getting **total Invoice Amount** from date 2020-12-23
expecting a single value but getting rows of data

[image]

Where I'm doing wrong ?

** Update **
Photo Added for better visualization. expecting 2000 as invoicetotal value

[image]

Comment: If you want a single value then you should remove `GROUP BY order_no`.

Comment: @forpas: database contains same order_id multiple time. Need to group by order_id first. Otherwise SUM is not correct.

Comment: Post sample data and expected results to clarify.

Comment: @forpas: Photo added

Comment: Is this the data in the table? If it is then why do you want 2000 as result? The total is 4000.

Comment: what do you want if invoice_total is different for two rows with the same order_no?

Comment: are there more cols in the table that aren't shown?  Something doesn't add up here - why are there duplicate rows in your example for the same order id?

Comment: @ysth: invoice_total is always same for same order_no

Comment: @forpas: table contains duplicate order_no. So i need to group them first. Then SUM `invoice_total`. invoice_total for order_no 201, 202 is 1200+800 = 2,000

Comment: Yes, I see that. Check my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First get the distinct combinations of `order_no` and `invoice_total` and then aggregate:

```
SELECT SUM(invoice_total) AS invoicetotal 
FROM (
  SELECT DISTINCT order_no, invoice_total 
  FROM p_orders 
  WHERE plain_date='2020-12-23' AND o_status='Delivered'
) t
```

Comment: I know they said invoice_total will always be the same for an order_no, but this will double-count orders in the case where it isn't.  Better to use group_by and max or min or get the total from the highest row or latest for some date.

Comment: @ysth the op's comment is: *invoice_total is always same for same order_no*. So there is no case an order_no to have different amount in different rows. So there is no need to GROUP BY order_no because this requires 2 levels of aggregation which is far less efficient.

Comment: they believe that, yes :)

Answer (score 1):

Your data is poorly structured; you really should have another table where order_no is the primary key and keep invoice_total in that.  As is, you could have different invoice_total values for the same order_no; you need to decide which to use in that case.  If you wanted to use the maximum, you would do:

```
SELECT SUM(invoicetotal) AS invoicetotal FROM (
    SELECT MAX(invoice_total) AS invoicetotal FROM `p_orders` WHERE `plain_date`='2020-12-23' AND `o_status`='Delivered' GROUP BY `order_no`
) AS distinct_orders;
```